# Do Marvel vs Capcom 3 and Ultimate MvC 3 share multiplayer?

Tags: ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3, marvel-vs-capcom-3

I got the vanilla version for very cheap and want to play against a friend of mine; however, he has the "Ultimate" version.

Is it possible to play together online? Or do I need to get the other version to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're different, distinct games. *Ultimate Marvel vs. Capcom 3* is a sequel to *Marvel vs. Capcom 3*, with similar but different mechanics and controls. They're not multiplayer compatible.

Comment: Aw bummer, guess I'll have to get the other one then. :(